# Using ternary operator with return

Tags: c#, .net, ternary-operator

Why I can't shortcut this :

```
if (await query.AnyAsync())
{
     return new ObjectResult(query);
}
     else
{
     return NotFound();
}
```

to this :

```
await query.AnyAsync() ? return new ObjectResult(query) : return NotFound();
```

How can I shortcut this ?

Comment: `var result = await query.AnyAsync() ? new ObjectResult(query) : NotFound(); return result ;` that's how you do it

Comment: How about this: `return await query.AnyAsync() ? new ObjectResult(query) : NotFound();`?

Comment: What is preventing you from using the conditional operator? (If you have a C# error then include that in the question.)

Comment: @Chetan Ranparia - I still haw an error which goes like that : "Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ObjectResult' and 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NotFoundResult'.

Comment: @Tetsuya Yamamoto - I have the same error like in Chetan Ranpariya's case

Comment: What's wrong with `if`?

Comment: I just want to do it more concisely

Comment: More concise does not equal more readable. I would always prefer `if` in this case and I would defenitely use my time for something more useful than changing this code (and even use more time to start a Q&A).

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a cast. To use a conditional expression you need to cast them to the same return type e.g.

```
return await query.AnyAsync() ? (ActionResult)new ObjectResult(query) : (ActionResult)NotFound();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but anyway:

These lines are wrong:

```
if (await query.AnyAsync())
{
     return new ObjectResult(query);
}
```

Either your query is already materialized, in which case it makes no sense to see if it has any entries *asynchronously*. Thhat would be overhead plain and simple. OR it is not materialized, in which case your `Any` call is useless, because it will only materialize it once then check if it has entries *and then materialize it again* for your result. That second call might as well contain no entries if something changes in your source between those calls. Best case is it's double the runtime for the same result.

So if you want to simplify and correct it:

```
var materialized = query.ToList();

if (materialized.Count != 0)
{
     return new ObjectResult(materialized);
}

return NotFound();
```

It does not get more simple. No need for a ternary operator here.

If you *want* a ternary operator, you will need to make sure it gets *expressions* of the same type, not *statements* (`return 0;` is a statement, `0` is an expression):

```
var materialized = query.ToList();

return (materialized.Count != 0)
    ? (IActionResult)new ObjectResult(materialized)
    : (IActionResult)NotFound();
```